# Problems asp.net 2.0 in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer-10

We have a website developed in vs2005 with framework 2.0.
The website works fine in all browsers unless IE10. The response.redirect doesn´t work and some buttons throws javascript errors.
If a force the explorer mode to IE10 compatibility view works fine, but we don´t want to tell all our users to force manually.
Anyone have the same problem?
Thanks a lot and best regards

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by inserting the App_Browsers map into the root map, containing a browser file BrowserFile.browser with the code:

```
    <browser refID="Default">
        <capabilities>
            <!-- To avoid wrong detections of e.g. IE10 -->
            <capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

Open your website in IE10

> Tools > Compatibility View Settings >
>   Click in Add to your domain website >
>   Close

Reload your website.

It´s worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript, CSS etc.

Try the fix given in the below link. Worked fine for me.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx